# Replacement of $_GET variable value

Tags: php

my html code

```
<form action = "search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="destination">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

my php code

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    echo $_GET['destination'];
 }
?>
```

MY URL

```
http://localhost/vb/guest/search.php?destination=USA
```

now i want that if i change the value of the variable then it will remain same that means if `destination=canada` or any other string then it will set the value `USA` again. please help, i m new to PHP

Comment: You could store it in the `$_SESSION` or a cookie and then if it's different [redirect to the right page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. *"Change the value of the variable*" where and what variable?

Comment: I also don't underrstand. What's the point of having the parameter if it will always be set to `USA` again?

Comment: i thought so .. is there any way without session to do that

Comment: Anything other than a session would probably allow the user to override what you're doing. They can change cookies, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$pathToUSA = '/search.php?destination=USA';

if (@$_GET['destination'] !== 'USA') {
    header('Location: ' . $pathToUSA);
}
```

> hope it helps.

Comment: yap.. it good.... but my target is to keep all get variable will remain unchanged do you have any idea about this ?????

Comment: If you are using a framework they maybe having a flash session (session is set and destroyed automatically once used). Other than using "frameworks" flash session you may implement it your self (set session and destroy it after using it).

Storing your destination in session I think would help but I'm sorry I'm not sure if it is the best practice for it.